# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' error in Flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, null, subtype

Question: I am building an world time app and i am getting an error that type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'.i am using variable isdaytime to change the background image in the app according to the time of the country, at day time backgroung image will be day and at night the bg image will be of night. but it seems the string is getting Null somewhere.   Please help me in solving the doubt

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYd7j.jpg)

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:universal_time_app/pages/choose_location.dart';
import'package:universal_time_app/pages/home.dart';
import'package:universal_time_app/pages/loading.dart';


void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/home',
  routes: {
    '/':(context)=>Loading(),
    '/home':(context)=>Home(),
    '/location':(context)=>ChooseLocation(),
  },
));
```

**Choose_location.dart**

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import'package:universal_time_app/services/universal_time.dart';
//import 'package:universal_time_app/pages/loading.dart';
//import 'package:universal_time_app/pages/home.dart';

class ChooseLocation extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChooseLocation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChooseLocationState createState() => _ChooseLocationState();
}

List<UniversalTime> locations = [
  UniversalTime(url: 'Europe/London', location: 'London', flag: 'UK.png',time:'',isdaytime: 1),
  UniversalTime(url: 'Europe/Athens', location: 'Athens', flag: 'Greece.png',time:'',isdaytime: 1),
  UniversalTime(url: 'Africa/Cairo', location: 'Cairo', flag: 'Egypt.png',time:'',isdaytime: 1),
  UniversalTime(url: 'Africa/Nairobi', location: 'Nairobi', flag: 'Kenya.png',time:'',isdaytime: 1),
  UniversalTime(url: 'America/Chicago', location: 'Chicago', flag: 'usa.png',time:'',isdaytime: 1),
  UniversalTime(url: 'America/New_York', location: 'New York', flag: 'usa.png',time:'',isdaytime: 1),
  UniversalTime(url: 'Asia/Seoul', location: 'Seoul', flag: 'South_Korea.png',time:'',isdaytime: 1),
  UniversalTime(url: 'Asia/Jakarta', location: 'Jakarta', flag: 'Indonesia.png',time:'',isdaytime: 1),
  UniversalTime(url: 'Asia/Kolkata', location: 'Delhi', flag: 'India.png',time:'',isdaytime: 1),
];

//void updateTime(snapshot,context);

void updateTime(index,context) async {
  //var instance = locations[index];
  UniversalTime instance = locations[index];
  await instance.getTime();
  //navigate to home screen

      Navigator.pop(context, {
        'location': instance.location,
        'flag': instance.flag,
        'time': instance.time,
        'isdaytime': instance.isdaytime
      });

}


class _ChooseLocationState extends State<ChooseLocation> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
        title: Text('Choose a location'),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount:locations.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0,horizontal:10.0 ),
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  updateTime(index,context);

                },
                title: Text(locations[index].location),
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/Flag_of_${locations[index].flag}'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:universal_time_app/services/universal_time.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  Map data={};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    data=data.isEmpty ? data: ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map;
    print(data);
    print('hi');

    String? bgImage='Nw1.jpg';

    //set bg image
    if (data['isdaytime'] == 1) {
      bgImage = 'Dw.jpg';
    }
    //print(bgImage);

    //String bgImage=data['isdaytime']?'Dw.jpg':'Nw1.jpg';
    return
       Scaffold(
         //backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent[100],x 
         body:Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             image: DecorationImage(
               image:AssetImage('assets/$bgImage'),
                   fit: BoxFit.cover,

             ),
           ),
           child: SafeArea(
            child:Column(
              children:<Widget>[
                TextButton.icon(
                    onPressed:() async {
                     dynamic result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');

                     setState(() {
                       data ={
                         'time' : result['time'],
                         'location' : result['location'],
                         'isdatime':result['isdaytime'],
                         'flag': result['flag'],

                       };
                     });

                     },
                    icon:Icon(Icons.edit_location_rounded,size:45.0,color: Colors.orange,),
                  label: Text(
                      'Edit Location',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),

                ),
                SizedBox(height: 230.0,),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      data['location'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                        fontSize: 50.0,
                        letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                Text(
                  data['time'],
                  style: TextStyle(

                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 70.0,
                    letterSpacing: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
         ),
      );
  }
}
```

**loading.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:universal_time_app/services/universal_time.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  const Loading({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}
class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
void setupWorldTime () async {
  UniversalTime instance=UniversalTime(location: 'Berlin',time: '', flag: 'Germany.png', url:'Europe/berlin',isdaytime:0);
     await instance.getTime();
     Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home',arguments: {
       'location':instance.location, 'flag':instance.flag,'time':instance.time,'isdaytime':instance.isdaytime,
     });
}

@override
void initState(){
    super.initState();
    setupWorldTime();
}
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      body:Center(
        child: SpinKitPouringHourGlassRefined(
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 100.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**universal_time.dart**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class UniversalTime {

  String location;
  String time;
  String flag;
  String url;
  int isdaytime;

  UniversalTime({
    required this.time,required this.isdaytime,
    required this.location,required this.flag,required this.url});

  Future <void> getTime() async {

//make request
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url'));
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    String datetime = data['datetime'];
    String offset1 = data['utc_offset'].substring(1,3);
    String offset2 = data['utc_offset'].substring(4,6);

    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
    now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset1), minutes: int.parse(offset2)));

    isdaytime=now.hour > 5 && now.hour < 20 ? 1:0;
    print(isdaytime);
    //print('aakash');
    //Set the time property
    time=DateFormat.jm().format(now);
    //print(time);
  }

}
```

Comment: I think you are passing null data somewhere in the app. You should do a null check everywhere to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, as this is a complex app and I can't exactly run it right now, however the error code that you got indicates that it got a null value when attempting to read a value on line 75 on home.dart (I know this because #0 on your stack was home.dart and it shows the line number)

this is line 75: `data['location']` this tells me that data does not have a location key, as I said, I could be wrong, and hopefully **`print(data)` on line 19 should be able to disprove this theory**. So before doing anything else, I would check to see what that print statement says. Anyway, here is my guess as to why this is happening to you.

`data=data.isEmpty ? data: ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map;`

this line says: if data is empty, data should be equal to data, else, data should be equal to `ModalRoute...`, I'd bet you got it backwards, it should be:

`data=data.isEmpty ? ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map: data;`

I also think its possible that home is being sent with no arguments as an initial route, but you would know that better than I.

Comment: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast
i got this error when i changed to the below line
 `data=data.isEmpty ? ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map: data; `

Comment: That probably means that `ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments` is null, are you sure you are passing the correct arguments?

Comment: yes i am,
the data is not being sent from choose location to home.dart

Comment: From what I could gather after running your code, choose location sends the data properly, and the error occurs when you first start the application because home is the initial route instead of loading, loading is never used, so on my end, the way to fix the issue was to remove the line that sets home as an initial route `initial route: '/home'` on main. If this is not the root of the issue and your project remains broken, I recommend you make a new project and move the dart files over, here is your code with my edits: https://pastebin.com/eJFeL92z

Answer (score 0):

The error message is an indication that somewhere in the code, you have assigned null to a var that requires a non-nullable String. Based on the code provided above, my best guess would be the result of your navigator in `home.dart` for the `result['location']` or `result['time']` is returning null

Comment: yes, but i am not getting how to fix it

Comment: this would mean that when you calling `Navigator.pop(context)` from the /location screen back to home, you're either not sending the arguments at all or declaring them differently, so when checked for the checked for the key in the home , its coming back as null

Comment: yes, exactly
i printed data in the choose location file and the data is printing
but the data is not sent back to home.dart
can you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: `Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/home',arguments: {
        'location': instance.location,
        'flag': instance.flag,
        'time': instance.time,
        'isdaytime': instance.isdaytime
      });`
i did this in the choose location.dart
but still it says type **'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'**